# SQL standard for timestamp in UTC or with timezone

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime, timestamp

I am searching for an standard SQL way to ensure independently from the database to have a column with a timestamp in UTC or as timestamp with the information of the timezone.
UTC example with stored timestamp UTC in DB-column:

- stored UTC value = **2014-01-01 15:30:00.000**

  local time India 21:00/9pm as local timestamp "2014-01-01 21:00:00.000"
- stored UTC value = **2013-12-31 23:30:00.000**

  local time India 05:00/5am as local timestamp "2014-01-01 05:00:00.000"

**In the UTC way the application has to cope with the timezoning**

And now the way I do not really know if possible, with timestamp and timezone with the above values

- stored local value = **2014-01-01 21:00:00.000**

  local time India 21:00/9pm as local timestamp "2014-01-01 21:00:00.000"

  but there is the timezone information?

  or how to get the timezone information of this timestamp?
- stored local value = **2014-01-01 05:00:00.000**

  local time India 05:00/5am as local timestamp "2014-01-01 05:00:00.000"

  but there is the timezone information?

  or how to get the timezone information of this timestamp?

Hopefully someone can help me out of the dark?
Are there good practices on timezoning issues and storing the data for international application?

Comment: Some of this depends on your RDBMS.  Different ones have the ability to store different things.  DB2 for the iSeries can't store Timezone at all.  Some RDBMSes don't store _historical_ timezones (ie, the US changed DST a few years back), which might be a problem.  The other part depends on what you're _doing_ with the information.  It's one thing if you're storing a log, and another if you're creating a calendar.  What are you doing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

To store a moment, a point on the timeline, define a database column of SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Store a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC. 
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieve a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Adjust from UTC to a time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  // Specify time zone in proper `Continent/Region` name, never the ambiguous non-standard 3-4 letter pseudo-zone such as `IST` or `PST`. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Adjust from a time zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

## Date-Time Is Not A String

Serious databases do not store date-time values as strings. Do not confuse a string *representation* generated by either the database or a Java library with the date-time value itself.

## Store UTC

Best practice is to use [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for your database and other storage, as well as the bulk of your business logic. Present in [local time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) only as expected by the user.

See Wikipedia for [standard date-time types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time). Even if you do not use Postgres, consult the outstanding [documentation on date-time data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). But I do recommend Postgres, for many reasons including its excellent support of date-time.

## Use `TIMESTAMPZ`

This Postgres expert makes the simple and wise recommendation: [Always Use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html)

The name of that data type is a **misnomer**, causing so much confusion. The time zone information is **not** stored. What it means is that the time zone indicated with incoming data is respected, and the stored value will be adjusted to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Think of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as `TIMESTAMP WITH RESPECT FOR TIME ZONE`. Reread this paragraph three times out loud, then read the above links, and do some experimenting to be sure you understand.

You may want to also store separately the original time zone information. Not for use in your business logic, but for use as logging info for debugging.

## Java

As for Java, be sure to avoid the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. They are notoriously troublesome. They are supplanted in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) by the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). Use either that package and/or the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4 library which inspired java.time.

## Time Zone

And in Java always specify the desired time zone. If omitted you'll implicitly be using the JVM's current default time zone. That implicit default means your results will vary across time and space. This is the root cause of much of the trouble in date-time work. If you want UTC, use the constant in Joda-Time, [`DateTimeZone.UTC`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC).

Ignoring time zones will not make your life easier.

## ISO 8601

This standard is extremely useful and sensible. Study the [excellent Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Should be your first choice for a String representation.

## Search StackOverflow

These issues have been covered on hundreds, if not thousands, of answers.